# Android Studio keeps disabling Dart support for my project

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am working on a Flutter project on my Android Studio and I decide to take a break and turn off my laptop and when I come back to Android Studio, Android studio decides to disable Dart support therefore changing the folder structure to Android native rather than Flutter.

I then go on settings to enable Dart, great! BUT all my folders have been restructured so the project won't run.

I am running on Windows, It happens when I turn off my computer.

I feel like Android studio "forgets" about Dart/Flutter.